# Function called by link_to, doesn't work even when hard coded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason, in my function `make_feed_preference`, the `@user.feed_preference` never changes, even if I hard code it to `@user.feed_preference = "foobar"` but it looks like `redirect_to 'posts'` is working fine.

The bug is that the `feed_preference` is always `nil` even after the `link_to` is pressed, so the (`if feed_preference == nil`) is always `true`. I still don't know what's causing this.

`make_feed_preference` is stored in the users_controller. What it does is shows a news feed, but sorted according to a preference value (e.g., "time", "trending_value", "followers")

```
<%= link_to displayIcon(1), {:action => :make_feed_preference, :id => current_user.id, :preference => "trending value",  :controller => "users"}, :method => :post %>
```

---

```
def make_feed_preference
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.feed_preference = params[:preference]

  @user.save

  redirect_to '/posts'
end
```

---

Note: i fixed it by attaching a new class to the users.

Comment: Jon, could you add your solution as an answer and 'accept' it please?

Answer (score 0):

I would be using a conditional here:

```
redirect_to '/posts', :notice => if @user.save
    'You have updated your feed preference.'
else
    'Your input was invalid.'
end
```

You'll find that the @user validations are probably failing.