# Rails: attributes not being saved even though I called @user.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running this function, and I KNOW that it gets called because the redirect_to is working. But for some reason, @user isn't! If it helps, @user is devise based.

```
def make_feed_preference
@user = current_user
#@user.feed_preference = params[:preference]

@user.feed_preference = "time"
@user.name = "Shoo Nabarrr"
@user.karma = 666

@user.save

redirect_to '/posts'
```

### end

I fixed it myself. I had to create a new class attached to users in order to get it to work. Lol.

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264856/function-called-by-link-to-doesnt-work-even-when-hard-coded - please update your existing questions instead of asking again in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any validations on this user? They are probably blocking this `save`. The `redirect_to` will be called regardless of whether or not the `save` passes or fails.

I would recommend doing it like this instead:

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to '/posts'
else
  render :feed_preference
end
```

Where `:feed_preference` is the form where users enter their feed preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where I want to be sure to update a flag or other field on a record even if the record has validation problems. (However, I would never do that with unvalidated user input.) You can do that thusly:

```
def make_feed_preference
  case params[:preference]
  when 'time', 'trending_value', 'followers'
    current_user.update_attribute 'feed_preference', params[:preference]
    flash[:notice] = 'Your feed preference has been updated.'
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Unknown feed preference.'
  end
  redirect_to '/posts'
end
```